# Why validation not working on form request?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am learning flask and made a small application. Now I am trying to learn `form`. I used a simple code to validate a `name` request and it should give error when the `field` remains empty. But it isn't giving one.

Main file :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.moment import Moment
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, validators

import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'abcd'
moment = Moment(app)


class Nameform(Form):
    name = StringField("whats your name?", [validators.Required()])
    submit = SubmitField('submit')


@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():

    api_call = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/moderators?order=desc&sort=reputation&site=stackoverflow')  # api call to stack for user with highest scores in des order

    var_1 = json.loads(api_call.text)

    var_2 = [{'link': value['link'], 'name': value['display_name'], 'user_id': value['user_id']} for value in var_1['items']]

    return render_template('index.html', posts=var_2, current_time=datetime.utcnow())


@app.route('/user/<id>/<user_name>')
def user(id, user_name):
    print id
    api_call = requests.get('https://api.stackexchange.com//2.2/users/'+id+'/reputation?site=stackoverflow')  # api call for reputation of click user

    var_1 = json.loads(api_call.text)
    return render_template('reputation.html', result=var_1, user_name=user_name)


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def user_form():
    name = None
    form = Nameform()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        form.name.data = ''
    return render_template('test_form.html', form=form, name=name)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Template for rendering:

```
<div class="page-header">
<h1>Hello, {% if name!= None %}{{ name }}{% else %}Stranger{% endif %}!</h1>
</div>
<form method=post>
{{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name() }}
{{ form.submit() }}
</form>
```

Why it is not throwing any error? when the field remains empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can render the error messages using `form.errors`. Note that you're also missing your CSRF token, which is required for validation since you didn't disable `WTF_CSRF_ENABLED`, so I've added `{{ form.csrf_token }}`. See [CSRF Protection](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/csrf.html).

```
<div class="page-header">
<h1>Hello, {% if name!= None %}{{ name }}{% else %}Stranger{% endif %}!</h1>
</div>
{% for field in form.errors %}
{% for error in form.errors[field] %}
    <div class="error">{{ error }}</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
<form method=post>
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{{ form.name.label }} {{ form.name() }}
{{ form.submit() }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not included the  `novalidate` attribute with form.
The `novalidate` attribute is used to tell the web browser to not apply validation to the fields in this form, which effectively leaves this task to the Flask application running in the server.
[For Sample code](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms)